# get MAC address from clients to server in java

Tags: java, client-server

I'm looking for a solution for a java based application(client-server),I need to get the (MAC address)  to clients on my network.
 i have server in my network and this server need to get a MAC address for all clients in my network. how can do this in java ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Java, but you wont be able to get the correct MAC address as there may be proxies or load balancers in between and you might get the MAC adress of intermediate proxies/LB. 
If you can store MAC adrress of machine on clients machine say in form of cookies(not a proper approach) and get them in requests, it will work.